# Characterization for the multipliers of Schwartz space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, function-spaces

Is the following true?

> A function $m:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb C$ is a Schwartz multiplier (i.e. $[f\mapsto mf]:S(\mathbb R^n)\to S(\mathbb R^n)$ is bounded linear) iff the following:
> For every $\alpha$ there is a $N_\alpha>0$ such that $|\partial^\alpha m(x)|\le (1+|x|)^{N_\alpha}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$?

If this is true, is there existed reference?

Comment: This is true (up to a multiplicative constant). It is in Laurent Schwartz's famous book *Théorie des distributions*. He called this multiplier space $\mathscr O_M(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thanks! I didn't locate the index of theorem for which characterize $\mathscr O_M$ in his book (since I don't know French:( ). Could you help pointing that?

Comment: It is also in Horváth's book *Topological Vector Spaces and Distribution* as Proposition 4.11.5 on page 417 with a 1½ page long proof.